# Resolve FK in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have some documents in firestore have some fields in it. like collection "details" looks like this

```
{
  id: "",
  fields1: "",
  userFK: Reference to users collection
}
```

Now I need to resolve userFK on the fly means that I don't want first fetch all the documents then query to userFk `userFK.get()`
Is there any method, its like doing a `$lookup` whick is supported in mongodb

Even In some case I want to fetch documents from "details" collection based of some specific fields in users

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get documents of multiple types from Firestore with a single read operation. To get the user document referenced by `userFK` you will have to perform a separate read operation.

This is normal when using NoSQL databases like Cloud Firestore, as they typically don't support any server-side equivalent of a SQL `JOIN` statement. The performance of loading these additional details is not as bad as you may think though, so be sure to measure how long it takes for your use-case before writing it off as not feasible.

If this additional load **is** prohibitive for a scenario, an alternative is to **duplicate** the necessary data of the user into each details document. So instead of only storing the reference to their document, you'd for example also store the user name.

This puts more work on the write operation, but makes the read operations simpler and more scalable. This is the common trade-off of space vs time, where in NoSQL databases you'll often find yourself trading time for space: so storing duplicate data.

If you're new to NoSQL data modeling, I highly recommend:

- [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)
- [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video)